# Does modifying class member objects in the destructor result in undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, destructor, undefined-behavior, lifetime

For example:

```
struct B { int b_; };
struct D : B
{
    ~D()
    { // D object's lifetime ends here
        d_ = 0;  // (1) undefined behavior?
        b_ = 0;  // (2) undefined behavior also?
    }
    int d_;
};
```

The [C++ Standard defines](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1) that for an object of type `D`, its **lifetime ends** when the destructor `~D()` call **starts**.

Can we interpret this to mean that modifying the object inside the destructor, as in (1), results in undefined behavior?

If so, does the same apply if we modify the base class subobject of `D`, as in (2)?

Comment: `its lifetime ends when the destructor ~D() call starts` No! The lifetime ends after! the constructor ends!

Comment: @Klaus that's incorrect. The lifetime ends when destructor call *starts*

Comment: @krzaq: I can do everything in the destructor with all its data members. There is nothing wrong with it before the closing '}' was reached. So why you think the lifetime ends on start of destructor?

Comment: @Klaus because the [standard says so](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1). I agree that it doesn't make much sense (at least at the first glance, there may be valid reasons why they defined this as such), but that's how it is.

Comment: @krzaq: Standard: `For an object with a non-trivial destructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object after the destructor *finishes* execution results in undefined behavior.` Finish, not start. So what I have overseen?

Comment: @Klaus The confusion stems from how *lifetime* is defined. That section does not define lifetime.

Comment: The code is fine for essentially the same reason that `struct X { int a; X() { a = 0; } };` is fine: It's OK to refer to members while the object is under construction or destruction transitively from within the constructor or destructor, respectively.

Comment: @Klaus I'm not talking about referring to members - that's valid (as I stated in my answer). I'm referring to the elusive lifetime, which is defined as: "The lifetime of an object o of type T ends when:

    if T is a class type with a non-trivial destructor ([class.dtor]), the destructor call starts" ( I linked the relevand section of the draft above)

Comment: @krzaq: Thanks for explanation!

Comment: @KerrekSB Very good point. I guess it's psychologically easier to accept that in constructors, that's what we're supposed to do - what else if not to initialize members (even though object _lifetime_ hasn't started yet)? For destructors, the Standard seems confusing at first - didn't know about the explicit special provisions krzaq quoted in the accepted answer.

Comment: @LeoHeinsaar: KerrekSB's example shows assignment, not initialisation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither access is undefined, they're both perfectly okay.

While you're right that the lifetime ends when the destructor starts, you can still use the object in limited ways, defined as:

> N4140 § 3.8 [basic.life] / 6
>
> Similarly, before the lifetime of an
>   object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy
>   has been allocated or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and
>   before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released,
>   any glvalue that refers to the original object may be used but only in
>   limited ways. *For an object under construction or destruction, see
>   [class.cdtor]*.

and [class.cdtor]:

> N4140 § 12.7 [class.cdtor] /1
>
> For an object with a non-trivial destructor, referring to any
>   non-static member or base class of the object after the destructor
>   finishes execution results in undefined behavior.

The above clearly states that only after the destructor finishes you can't touch members of that object.

Comment: Seems thorough, thanks. I'll rephrase the question to make (1) a question so not to confuse other viewers.

Answer (score 2):

None of the examples you've shown are undefined behavior. They are perfectly defined.

The class instance exists until the destructor returns. The object's members get destroyed not before the destructor gets called, but after it returns. As such, modifying the members of the class, in the destructor, is completely kosher. And the superclass does not get destroyed until the subclass gets completely destroyed, so modifying the superclass's members is perfectly fine, too.

Very generally speaking, an object gets destroyed by the following process:

1. The destructor gets called.
2. The class members get destroyed, in reverse order of their initial construction.
3. Steps 1 and 2 are repeated for the object's superclasses.

(I am ignoring virtual inheritance, for simplicity, and it's not relevant here).